# Removing all duplicates if condition is met

Tags: sql

I have a data set:

```
id  type
1000 0
1000 1
1000 0
1001 0 
1001 0 
1001 0
```

I want to remove all the id as long as type >=1, in this case all the id=1000, how should I approach this?

Comment: You have no examples in your data where `type > 1`.  Hence the question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: You need to elaborate your question, In your example there is no data to match your conditions

Comment: need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean >= 1 and you want a *result set* that filters out those ids, you can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.type >= 1);
```

Comment: yes, i meant >=1. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want all records for which no other record exists with the same id and `type >= 1`, you can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.id = t.id = t1.type >= 1)
```

If you just want the distinct `id`s that satisfy this condition, then you can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select id
from mytable
group by id
having max(id) < 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Aaron: welcome! Note:you are free to accept any answer that you like. But is there any specific reason why you accepted the other answer, while it is identical to the first part of mine and was posted a bit later?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

`select distinct id,type from mytable where type >= 1`